# hyperledger composer namespace is not defined for type

Tags: javascript, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

In .qry file when i try to write a query composer throws an error "namespace is not defined for type." I have imported perishable network example and haven`t made any changes except for including a .qry file.

I have attached the screenshot for reference.

[image]

Comment: acme ???, review your package if this exists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

namespace was defined wrongly, We are suppose to directly access the resource instead of using Participant or asset.

correct namespace

org.acme.shipping.perishable.Grower